# Springboot Thymeleaf Cache page

Tags: html, intellij-idea, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I implement a client application. This application consume a Rest webservice and these service return and html page as a variable in a model. 
I take these html page successfully from Rest Service and try to write to a blank html page.
My code to write html page.

```
public void writeToHtml(ResponseModel response) {

    FileWriter fWriter = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        fWriter = new FileWriter(src/main/resources/templates/test.html);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
        writer.write(response.getHtmlPage());
        writer.newLine();
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

These function can take htmlPage from ResponseModel and write successfully to test.html
Untill there everthing work properly and my controller display it on secreen.

However, if I again call same Rest service, it can again write to "test.html" but, on the screen it shows the first created html page.
Probably it cache the first html and if I rewrite again. I just take cache one.

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testPath", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String payment(RequestModel paymentInfoModel, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseModel response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, ResponseModel.class);
        writeToHtml(response);

    return "test";

}
```

Could you help me to solve these issue ?

IDEA : Inteliji

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem a bit differently:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testPath", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
@ResponseBody
public String payment(RequestModel paymentInfoModel, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();  
   ResponseModel response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, ResponseModel.class);
   writeToHtml(response);

   return response.getHtmlPage();
}
```

So I don't need to create an HTML page.